# Galaxy S6 not seen by pc at all

Tags: adb, usb, samsung, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have one week old S6 and now tried to use `adb`.

I unlocked developer mode, enabled USB debugging, connected to usb and nothing happened. `adb devices` shows empty list, `lsusb` on mac and linux as well as mac's "system information" app doesn't see any new usb device when I connect the phone. Nothing happens in `dmesg` too.

The phone displays "charger connected" notification. No mtp/ptp notification appears.

I tried to use different computers (two linux boxes and one macbook), different cables, nothing. Other android devices (such as old note2 and some noname stuff) works well.

I tried also other person's S6. Result it the same so I don't think it is some kind of damaged socket or so on.

What's going on? Am I missing something? Maybe some security setting prevents USB from working?

**UPD**

This doesn't look as a "driver" issue at all. `lsusb` shows *all* usb devices even if the system doesn't know how to deal with them.

Comment: You downloaded and installed the USB driver appropriate for your desktop computer(s) from Samsung site?

Comment: It appears that Samsung has done something special, meaning you need extra drivers in addition to the standard ADB ones. Put your phone's model number in http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads and scroll down to Manuals & Downloads. For at least one model, it looks like the drivers are Windows-only; if you can't access a Windows machine you could *try* using WINE (https://www.winehq.org), although udev may stop you.

Comment: Actually, AFAIR, even devices unknown for the system appears in lsusb so it is not a "drivers" problem.

Comment: If you have a custom recovery (or know someone with one), does the phone show up in adb when booted into recovery?

Comment: My device (not Samsung but some other) tends to behave in the similar fashion occasionally. In my case, the system detects nothing except that the charging LED shows power status. The solution that works for me is to keep rebooting the device multiple times, until it goes away. IDT whether the issue is with the socket (1.5 yrs old device) or the cable, but the issue withers away.  I know it makes no sense, but you may try this technique it nothing good works. // I once even had to restore nandroid backup.

Comment: My S6 is seen by the OS (Ubuntu 14.04) and MTP works but I cannot figure out how to make adb to see it.

Comment: @juzzlin you're lucky man!.. Just check udev rules ( http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html )

Comment: THE FIX!!! (for me):
 In the developer options under the "Networking" category, there is an option called "USB configuration". Click on that and you will see the option "MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)". Turn it on.  ,,, Mine was set to "Charging" for some reason..but instantly connected once I enabled MTP option. I would put this as the answer but I'm required to have 10 reputation points...and I ain't got time to be earnin'.. The only thing I got time for now is MEDIA TRANSFERRIN', BABY!

Comment: The fix for me was to find update the driver via the Windows Device Manager. Once I did that it all worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad but true, it's a hardware issue. As far as I understand, the board containing usb socket needs to be replaced.

PS:
Also the worldwide warranty that I was promised to have in *official* (listed on samsung.com) retail shop doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting very frustrated with my Samsung Galaxy S6 and my new Dell Precision M3800 and USB connectivity. Apparently the S6 is not fully compatible with USB 3 connections. I could not get it to connect (other than charging) to any of the 3 USB 3 ports on my laptop (no usb 2 on the new Dell). It connects fine to my older laptop (USB 2), so I decided to try connecting a USB 2 hub to my new Dell and the phone to the hub, and it works!
So, Samsung, please fix this!

Comment: This also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  Samsung buried the option to turn USB debugging on deep inside the Settings menu.  You have to enable it in order to use ADB with the S6 (or any other Android device)

Have a look [here](http://www.solvemix.com/index.php/android-smartphones/511-samsung-galaxy-s6-activate-usb-debugging-how-to-do).

Comment: Nope. This is a hardware issue. Authorized service center confirmed it but refused to perform warranty repair.

Comment: Dood its not samsung its with every Android phone. Samsung didn't buried that thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hardware issue, or a computer driver issue.  It's whatever the USB "driver" is on the S6 itself, because a factory reset resolves the issue.

I can't figure out what it is that breaks it, whether it's a setting change or an app getting deleted.  If anyone's aware I'd love to know.

Comment: Hard reset had no effect, that was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue with my S6 Edge(+). Found to be junkie usb cable. Switched to a quality cable and device showed up.

Comment: OP on the question noted that they already tried with different cables and that didn't work out, so I'm not sure how this answer would help.

Comment: Yeah, the only advice that may help for similar situation -- "Don't trust Samsung and their partners".

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but my phone use to actually work when I connected it through USB. Maybe this is a software update issue? Sometime ago after updating I noticed the problem.