# Samsung Galaxy S6 no MTP,PTP connection error

Tags: samsung, usb-connection-mode, mtp, samsung-galaxy-s-6, sprint

I am having trouble with my device when connecting it through usb. My device registers through odin in download mode but that's it. When i connect it to my pc my phone just notifies me that its charging. My pc will not detect it period even after uninstalling/reinstalling drivers. I've tried using Linux, MAC, Windows 7,8,8.1, and 10 still no luck. This is extremely frustrating considering i can not transfer anything unless i upload everything through some form of cloud storage. I have even tried changing the radio settings on my phone from MTP to MTP ADB and several others in hope that this would fix it. I have also tried flashing other versions of support OS versions even going back to 5.0.1.

Comment: Don't know how to fix the MTP, but a more direct workaround than cloud storage is to fire up a simple FTP server on your phone. [This one](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=ftp&fdid=be.ppareit.swiftp_free) is open-source and works well in my experience.

Comment: but the question is uploading something from my device to that server is still cloud based scenario. Which is reliant on my upload speeds which is between 10/15mbps when you"re uploading a 3 gigabyte file that takes some time. I used filezilla on my linux machine at first but really didn't solve my issue

Comment: Double-check you're using the USB cable that came with your device. Try switching USB ports (especially if your device has some USB 2 and some USB 3). Restart in between driver uninstall/installs. Try another PC. Double-check you have the correct drivers (check the Samsung site to confirm or manually download them). Sometimes these things matter and will help, sometimes they don't--it depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/109991/274